# What new features my tablet gains in the passage between Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: tablet, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I just received the official ICS upgrade for my Asus TF101 (Wi-Fi only version) and I immediately noticed that the device seems faster and has a renewed look & feel.

But what other features the new OS version brings for tablets?

Comment: Please refer to this Meta discussion: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/620/what-to-do-about-whats-new-in-version-questions

Answer (score 2):

Selected excerpts from the official [Android 4 Platform Highlights](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html) document:

> - The biggest changes will be for phones upgrading from Gingerbread to Ice Cream Sandwich, rather than for tablets upgrading from Honeycomb,
>     as a lot of the new UI features were introduced in Honeycomb.
> - The UI change is a big difference and brings Honeycomb's Recent Apps button for easier access to multi-tasking to the main-line Android
>     platform along with the System bar that it sits on.
> - The standard Lock  Screen now has quick access to the Camera and Notifications, and there will be album art and controls for music
>     playing in the Music app on the lockscreen.
> - When an incoming call arrives, users can now quickly respond by text message, without needing to pick up the call or unlock the device.
> - Improved text input and spell-checking on the standard Android 4 keyboard
> - Android 4.0 introduces a powerful new voice input engine that offers a continuous "open microphone" experience and streaming voice
>     recognition.
> - To meet the needs of users with tiered or metered data plans, Android 4.0 adds new controls for managing network data usage.
> - Enhanc[ing] the accessibility of Android 4.0 for blind or visually impaired users. Most important is a new explore-by-touch mode that
>     lets users navigate without having to see the screen.
> - A new People app that offers richer profile information, including a large profile picture, phone numbers, addresses and accounts, status
>     updates, events, stream items, and a new button for connecting on
>     integrated social networks.
> - The user's own contact information is stored in a new "Me" profile, allowing easier sharing with apps and people.
> - an updated Calendar app brings together personal, work, school, and social agendas.
> - a new visual voicemail features integrates incoming messages, voice transcriptions, and audio files from one or more providers.
> - The Camera app includes many new features... continuous focus, zero shutter lag exposure... Stabilized image zoom... users can now take
>     snapshots at full video resolution just by tapping the screen as video
>     continues to record... built-in face detection locates faces in the
>     frame and automatically sets focus... single-motion panorama mode...
> - Redesigned Gallery app with photo editor
> - Live Effects for transforming video
> - instantly sync and manage Google Chrome bookmarks from all ... accounts
> - Android Beam for NFC-based sharing [requires NFC hardware integrated into the device]
> - Face Unlock
> - Wi-Fi Direct lets users connect directly to nearby peer devices over Wi-Fi
> - built-in support for connecting to Bluetooth Health Device Profile (HDP) devices... users can connect to wireless medical devices and
>     sensors in hospitals, fitness centers, homes, and elsewhere

Also your manufacturer, Asus, may have added or updated their own specific software, and some of the new features may only be available if your manufacturer hasn't customized/replaced the original Android app.